# Plot histogram between texts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, histogram

There is a simple dataframe where I want to plot the histograms.
The problem is: I want to put text before AND after the histograms. Any ideas?
At the moment both print-snippets were put before histograms.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

print("text before histogram")

df.hist(bins=30, figsize=(15, 10))

print("text after histogram")
```

[image]

Comment: Is [matplotlib.pyplot.figtext(x, y, s, fontdict=None, **kwargs)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figtext.html#matplotlib-pyplot-figtext) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.show()` before the second print in order to tell Matplotlib (the library that use Pandas to made the plot) *show my plot*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

print("text before histogram")

df.hist(bins=30, figsize=(15, 10));

plt.show()

print("text after histogram")
```

[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoCXx.png)